# How do I find the path to the tclsh running my script?

Tags: tcl

From my Tcl script, I would like to find the path to the `tclsh` executable which is running my script (like `sys.executable` in Python), or at least find how the `tclsh` was invoked from the command line (like `$^X` in Perl)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found it by myself: It's

```
info nameofexecutable
```

Comment: It _can_ fail when your code is running in a Tcl interpreter embedded in larger program (depending on how that program called `Tcl_FindExecutable()`). That's not usually a big problem though.